# Excel Filtering through list via Formula Logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to scroll through my list of thousands of email logs and find all people with the name of "Yoda" and get the ID number where Yoda is located.

I've tried formulas for vlookups and index matching but it doesn't work because I get repeated IDs. How can I filter my list as a formula so that I can just get all IDs for Yoda? I will be placing the formula for the IDs in another worksheet.

Email Logs:

```
Character       ID

Yoda@gmail.com  789
Yoda@yahoo.com  664
Luke@gmail.com  113
Anakin@bing.com 115
Jabba@gmail.com 998
Yoda@wired.com  446
Luke@yahoo.coom 500
```

What I would like to see in my new worksheet is:

```
Yoda    Luke   Anakin   Jabba

789     113    115      998
664     500
446
```

Comment: Have your tried Conditioning Formatting and sort the list using Color?

Comment: Yes, I can filter it easily myself by setting the logs as a table then filtering to text "Yoda". However, this isn't convenient for the rest of the logs I'll have do, 15+ other characters.

Comment: If you like it as a long term solution, I would use VBA, otherwise, you just have to filter every step.

Comment: I have tried to use vba but since my email logs contain different variations I can't filter all the variations for "Yoda". Plus, I can get new variations throughout the week so I'll have to manually add those filters into my VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my problem! I couldn't record a macro to filter my list using the "Search Filter" for Yoda (and many other names) since there were too many Yoda variations (see Error Image). Instead I recorded a macro that uses the "Text Filters" and I filtered to text that contains "Yoda". I did this for the rest of my characters and I was able to automate my filtered results onto a new worksheet.

Thank you all for your contributions!

[image: Search Filter]

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly simply with `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` which has been available in Excel since 2010.  For earlier versions, VBA would be a good alternative.

All of the operations, except for creating the two custom columns, can be done from the User Interface.  The custom columns require entering formulas into the create custom column dialog.

In Power Query:

- Add a custom column to remove the `@domain` portion of the email.  Name the column `CharName`

---

```
Text.Start([Character],Text.PositionOf([Character],"@"))
```

[image]

- Remove the original `Characters` column
- Group by `CharName`

[image]

- Add a custom column that converts the resultant `Table` to a List

---

```
Table.Column([Count],"ID")
```

[image]

- In the resultant `IDs` column, select the double arrow at the upper right of the column, and select to `Extract Values` with a comma delimiter
- Split that column by delimiter (the comma) and new columns will be created
- Remove the original `Table` column
- Transpose the entire table
- Promote the contents of the first row to be Headers

Here is the M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Character", type text}, {"ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "CharName", each Text.Start([Character],Text.PositionOf([Character],"@"))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Character"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"CharName"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [ID=number, CharName=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "IDs", each Table.Column([Count],"ID")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"IDs", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "IDs", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"IDs.1", "IDs.2", "IDs.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"IDs.1", Int64.Type}, {"IDs.2", Int64.Type}, {"IDs.3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Count"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns1"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Yoda", Int64.Type}, {"Luke", Int64.Type}, {"Anakin", Int64.Type}, {"Jabba", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

And here is the final result, from your original data:

[image]

If you prefer a VBA method, you can create a dictionary of collections of ID's for each character.  You'll need to work your way through the code below to understand it, and adapt it to your particular workbook & worksheet setup.

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub charIDs()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim D As Dictionary, COL As Collection, sKey As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim V As Variant

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Source")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

Set D = New Dictionary
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare

'Create a dictionary of collections of Id's for each character
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    sKey = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "@")(0)
    If Not D.Exists(sKey) Then
        Set COL = New Collection
        COL.Add vSrc(I, 2)
        D.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=COL
    Else
        D(sKey).Add vSrc(I, 2)
    End If
Next I

'create results array
I = 0
For Each V In D.Keys
    I = IIf(I > D(V).Count, I, D(V).Count)
Next V

ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To D.Count)

'Populate
J = 0
For Each V In D.Keys
    J = J + 1
    vRes(0, J) = V
    For I = 1 To D(V).Count
        vRes(I, J) = D(V)(I)
    Next I
Next V

'size and fill results range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)?  You'll want Small (15) to do this in ascending order

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$8,AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($A$1:$A$8)-1+POWER(10,9*--(LEFT($A$1:$A$8,LEN("Yoda"))<>"Yoda")), ROW()-1),1),"")
```

The `-1+POWER(10,9*--(LEFT($A$1:$A$8,LEN("Yoda"))<>"Yoda"))` bit means that any non-Yoda values throw an error in `INDEX`, resulting in `=""`

Comment: I tried your formula when I put my values into
  
`Column A                      
1  Yoda@gmail.com          789
2  Yoda@yahoo.com         664
3  Luke@gmail.com          113
4  Anakin@bing.com         115
.
.
.`

Column B
But the formula doesn't return any value.